# How does DVM manage the memory when the compiled code get loaded in DVM?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, jvm, dalvik

When the Java byte code is loaded in JVM, the JVM divides the memory in the following sections

1.**Heap**

2.**Stack**

3.**Code**

4.**Static**

How the same take place in DVM? Please guide me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I known, the DVM manages memory the same way as the JVM.  Obviously, there will be some differences in the fine details, but if you understand one you should be able to understand the other.

However, your understanding is a little wrong ... with respect to the JVM.  For HotSpot JVMs (at least), both code and statics (class frames) are allocated within the Heap.  I understand that the permgen heap is used but that is heap space, and the space will be garbage collected under certain circumstances.

Comment: yeah...I accept...the GC works same as that of JVM GC. my confusion is here, the stack frame get destroyed as soon as method get executed, but I read the DVM  uses register based opcodes...

Comment: help me, I am curious to know the basic of DVM as I know it will help me while designing the app

Comment: @TechKida - that won't make any difference.  The JVM's "opstack" is not the stack.  It is just a way of *describing* the way that intermediate expression results are handled.  The actual stack is the place where local variables and method parameters are stored, along with the method return information.

Comment: @TechKida - I don't see why this should have any impact on how you design an app.  The JVM and DVM "work the same" from an application's perspective.  (The differences that matter to you are in the higher level APIs.)

Comment: Thank you very much..it helped me to clear misconception,at application level work I think instead of worrying it , I must focus on how to use available APIs...